# Sandboxing Firefox using firejail: Download directory

Tags: ubuntu, firejail

I have been using firejail for sandboxing my application in Ubuntu.  It has a `--private` option. I was using

```
firejail --private=/home/user/Desktop firefox
```

When I try to download a file from Firefox it stores it in a directory called `Download` inside firejail. Is it possible to get it to store in `/home/user/Desktop`?

Answer (score 2):

[Firejail manpage](https://firejail.wordpress.com/features-3/man-firejail/) says:

> --private
>         Mount  new  /root  and  /home/user  directories  in   temporary
>         filesystems.  All  modifications are discarded when the sandbox
>         is closed.
>
> ```
>   Example:
>   $ firejail --private firefox
> ```
>
> --private=directory
>         Use directory as user home.
>
> ```
>   Example:
>   $ firejail --private=/home/netblue/firefox-home firefox
> ```

So this means that Firefox will see `/home/user/Desktop` as `/home/user/`, and you should be able to store downloaded files in `/home/user/Desktop` without doing anything else (assuming default profile).
I have tested it with `firejail 0.9.58.2` with the default profile plus the `--private=/home/user/Desktop` flag on `Debian 10`.

If Firefox is automatically saving it to the newly created `Downloads` folder when run with the `--private=dir` flag, then you should just disable the auto saving feature of downloaded files in Firefox: `Preferences -> General -> Files and Applications -> Always ask where to save files`. When you do that, and when firefox asks for where to download, the folder that you see as `user` (home dir) in firefox is actually `/home/user/Desktop`.

**Edit:** It is normal that the Firefox settings get reset every time you start in `--private=dir`, because to Firefox this is your `home` folder and it looks for the config files `.mozilla`. If it cannot find it, it will create one for you, with the default settings. Invoke firefox normally with `/usr/bin/firefox`, then change the download setting I mentioned. After that copy `~/.mozilla` directory to `/home/user/Desktop` and finally you can run firefox with the `--private=/home/user/Desktop` option.

Comment: Yes i did disable the auto save feature but somehow the settings that i change keeps on reverting back after i close the sandbox..actually i maybe not be able to convey it that we'll in the question..it stores in /home/user/Desktop/Downloads on using the above filter..If i change the filter to /home/user/Documents it will store in /home/user/Documents/Downloads

Comment: @network I have edited my answer. Try it and let us know.